# Issues with Expo Auth Session implementation

Tags: react-native, oauth, expo

I am having issues with the implementation of Expo Auth Session.

I am trying Google Oauth Login in Expo Auth Session as documented here: https://docs.expo.io/guides/authentication/#google

```
WebBrowser.maybeCompleteAuthSession();

const GoogleButton = () => {
  // Endpoint
  const discovery = useAutoDiscovery('https://accounts.google.com');

  // Request
  const [request, response, promptAsync] = useAuthRequest(
    {
      clientId: 'MYID',
      scopes: ['email', 'profile'],
      // For usage in managed apps using the proxy
      redirectUri: makeRedirectUri({
        // For usage in bare and standalone
        native: 'com.googleusercontent.apps.MYID://redirect',
        useProxy: true,
      }),
    },
    discovery,
  );

  console.log(request);
  console.log(response);

  return (
    <Button
      onPress={promptAsync}
      icon={GoogleIcon}
    />
  );
};
```

The browser opens, I can successfully log in with google, but when I get redirected to the app, response resolves to `Object { "type": "dismiss", }`

I also tried implementing oauth with a different oauth service:

```
WebBrowser.maybeCompleteAuthSession();

const HiveButton = () => {
  // Endpoint
  const discovery = {
    authorizationEndpoint:
      'https://hivesigner.com/login-request/my.app',
  };

  // Request
  const [request, response, promptAsync] = useAuthRequest(
    {
      scopes: ['posting'],
      // For usage in managed apps using the proxy
      redirectUri: makeRedirectUri({
        useProxy: true,
      }),
    },
    discovery,
  );

  console.log(request);
  console.log(response);

  return (
    <Button
      onPress={promptAsync}
      icon={HiveIcon}
    />
  );
};
```

The browser opens, I can log in successfully, but instead of being redirected to the app, I get "Something went wrong trying to finish signing in. Please close this screen to go back to the app." on auth.expo.io/@me/myapp, even though the parameter code has the correct login token that I want to pass to my app.

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

-Login to your expo account:
on command line type:

```
expo login
##then your account credencials##
```

then restart your expo instance:

```
expo start
```

And everything should work fine

Comment: This issue is not about expo login

Answer (score 0):

I have the exact same issue. I've posted on the Expo forums too and tried to contact the devs about it but nobody's responding to me. I think it's been broken with a recent change. If you look at the redirect URL it's supposed to have two more query parameters one for the authentication URL and one for the return URL

Answer (score 0):

I’ve now solved the second issue by using AuthSession.startAsync instead:

```
 const handleLogin = async () => {
    const redirectUrl = AuthSession.getRedirectUrl({ useProxy: true });
    const response = await AuthSession.startAsync({
      authUrl: `https://hivesigner.com/login-request/my.app?redirect_uri=${redirectUrl}&scope=posting`,
    });
console.log(response)
}
```

Instead of using AuthSession for Google login I’m using the `expo-google-sign-in` implementation

Comment: This package has been deprecated in favor of `expo-auth-session`'s Google provider (for web-browser based authentication)

Answer (score 0):

Use `expo-auth-session/providers/google` from the https://docs.expo.dev/guides/authentication/#google example

```
import * as React from 'react';
import * as WebBrowser from 'expo-web-browser';
import * as Google from 'expo-auth-session/providers/google';
import { Button } from 'react-native';

WebBrowser.maybeCompleteAuthSession();

export default function App() {
  const [request, response, promptAsync] = Google.useAuthRequest({
    expoClientId: 'GOOGLE_GUID.apps.googleusercontent.com',
    iosClientId: 'GOOGLE_GUID.apps.googleusercontent.com',
    androidClientId: 'GOOGLE_GUID.apps.googleusercontent.com',
    webClientId: 'GOOGLE_GUID.apps.googleusercontent.com',
  });

  React.useEffect(() => {
    if (response?.type === 'success') {
      const { authentication } = response;
      }
  }, [response]);

  return (
    <Button
      disabled={!request}
      title="Login"
      onPress={() => {
        promptAsync();
        }}
    />
  );
}
```

Comment: what we do with this copy past from expo docs ?

Comment: instead of `useAuthRequest` use these code